# Where could you download the static library/header for the standard math library for c?

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

I have googled and looked all over, but can't find it ANYWHERE. Anyone know where to get it?

Comment: You are talking about math.h?

Comment: There is no 'the' standard math library. There is one official specification and a variety of implementations of the specification.

Comment: Search for fdlibm to find the implementation on which most others are based.

Comment: A little context. You're #include <math.h> in your code and it isn't found?

Comment: Ok, let me explain. Some APIs I use for microcontrollers require the "standard math library" be linked to. Well, my IDE doesn't provide much in the way of libraries, so I have googled it, and I have found nothing. I just need to know where to get it. And yes, I am talking about math.h.

Comment: And your IDE and toolset is... ? I ask because most decent compilers, OS platforms, etc, have decent versions of what you're looking for already.

Comment: This is like asking where to download the standard C compiler. We have no idea what machine or C implementation you're running on. And why is there a C++ tag on your question? "yes, I am talking about math.h" -- then why does your question mention a library and have a static-libraries tag? A header file and a library are not the same thing.

Comment: AVR Studio 4.0. I am programming CEEN-Bots.

Comment: @JimBalter Because I AM programming in C++, but using some C libraries.

Comment: Well, I need the math library static library apparently, according to documentation that was provided to me. And I would need a header file to reference to the functions the static library would define.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding the linker command `-lm`?

Comment: Um, no, my IDE doesn't allow that apparently. Instead, it lists all linkable objects, which you double click on to link to.

Comment: I suggest checking with Atmel.

Comment: "Linking with the libm.a is a new requirement as of API revision v1.02.000R and up." That is word to word from documentation. And libm is the math library. And no, I shouldn't check with Atmel, because the API I am talking about isn't FROM them. CEEN-Bots are basically little computers on wheels. The people who make them also make the APIs for them. And the documentation I am reading from is from the University of Omaha, which helps develop the API. I am trying to program these CEEN-Bots, and it is not easy, so the CEEN-Bot API is the thing I have talked about.

Comment: You've just had a 'baptism by fire' on SO. Welcome, nonetheless.  Please take the relevant information from your comments and use them to create a question which is complete (and then delete your comments). You should have gleaned from the comments that if the API demands the use of the library, then the SDK used should also provide the library. Or, perhaps, the people who provide the API.  Make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK. You might usefully provide some URLs, too, to where the various parts of the system you're working with are available. Please read the [FAQ] too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. After a little research on the documentation for this, I believe the library you're looking for is part of the WinAVR-GCC Toolkit, the static library kit for CEENBoT-API, and a few other things. According to the [links](http://www.ceen.unomaha.edu/CEENBoT/API/CEENBoT-API_GettingStarted%28Rev1.07%29.pdf) at UnOmaha, there are a variety of things you need to program those little gems. But the configuration of what I believe you're looking for is on page 11 of the linked PDF. There is a fairly nice walkthrough of configuring the project.

These robots are effectively programmed using a cross-compiler, and configuring them is always a fun agenda. I wish you the best of luck. (and now you made me want to go out and buy one as soon as I clear it with my wife, cuz these things look damn-cool).

Comment: This things are cool, IF you can figure out how to get everything compiled and shipped over to the bot's firmware first. It is a little tricky, but I am sure I will get the hang of it. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

math library is part of C standard library. It should be provided with compiler.